# Why does my Toyota Camry Hybrid (2008) keep consuming tires?

Tags: tires, toyota

I bought my Toyota Camry Hybrid new in 2008.  I specify Hybrid because I know the weight distribution is somewhat different.

I've driven 50,000.  I live in South Florida.  I've already replaced all four tires on this car twice.  Last time in June 2012 with Yokohamas.  I get them rotated on my 6000 mile oil changes (the suggestion for the newer cars was less frequent changes).

The new tires are already going bald.  I'm going to have to buy another four tires.

What's going on?  Ideas?  I can add as much additional evidence as we need.

**HISTORY**

I will provide a history as soon as I can; apparently I don't have all the receipts.  Alignment numbers won't be able to be provided without further request from the dealer; Toyota aligns to "Factory Specs" according to the receipts.

Comment: Yes, please add the specific model of tires.  A picture of the wear pattern would also be useful.

Comment: Have you recently/ever had an alignment done?  That's the usual suspect.  If you have, please post up the printout of the results.

Answer (score 3):

Check your alignment.  Are the tires going bald on one side of the tire more than the other? For instance are they more bald on the inside or outside of the tire?  Usually this is caused by bad alignment.  Brian said it right, if you have the printout of an alignment post that up.

BTW are all 4 tires bad?